# Close Bootstrap progress bar upon reaching 100% full

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, progress

I'm doing a `while` loop to fill up my Bootstrap progress bar from `0` to `100`.

This works, however I want to hide the progress bar as it reaches 100% full. I've tried using `setTimeOut` without success.

Even though the `while` loop of 0-100 can be done in a micro-second, the bar still fills up incrementally.

```js
var i = 0;
while(i <= 100){
  $('#progress').attr('aria-valuenow', i).css('width', i + '%');
  i++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="progress">
  <div id="progress" class="progress-bar progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem with `setTimeout` is that your function this way will call `setTimeout` a lot more often than it can increment, since this is not synchronous (pretty basic stuff). It doesn't wait to complete. You need to debounce with something like `lodash`. Also, do not forget about passing context in javascript when using these functions, since you are passing them out of scope. Try setting debugger statements and opening a browser console or printing `this` within these functions

Comment: sorry btw I answered so quickly I gotta catch a train

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All done. No Bootstrap makes it much easier.

```js
updateProgress(0);

function updateProgress(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (i <= 100) {
      $('#progress').width(i + '%'); 
      i++;
      updateProgress(i);
    } else {
     $('#progress').hide();
     $('#progress').width('1%');  
    }
  }, 4);
}
```

```css
#progress {
  background-color: #007bff;
  height: 3px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="progress"></div>
```